# Every time I try to create or replace a view I get Syntax error line 2 at position 1 unexpected 'COLUMN_NAME'

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

As the question states. Every time I try to create a view it gets mad about whatever first column I am calling it and it says "unexpected 'Column_Name'" whatever that column may be.

Am I dumb or is something else screwed up? Not that those are mutually exclusive...

```
-- Enterprise Factory Data Warehouse : EFDW

-- use appropriate role
USE ROLE EFDW_DEV_DB_DEV;
--USE ROLE EFDW_PROD_DB_DEV;

-- use appropriate Database
USE DATABASE EFDW_DEV_DB;
--USE DATABASE EFDW_PROD_DB;

-- use SUPPLYCHAIN_LOGISTICS schema
USE SCHEMA SUPPLYCHAIN_LOGISTICS;


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------- Information Object creation-------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Demand Data Information Object
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW SUPPLYCHAIN_LOGISTICS.DEMAND(
    MATERIAL_NUM COMMENT 'Material or Part Number',
    RSF_INDICATOR COMMENT 'Rough(R), Semi-Finished(S), or Finished(F) Indicator',
    SOURCE_PLANT_CODE COMMENT 'Plant code for the sending facility related to SAP',
    SOURCE_FACILITY_CODE COMMENT 'Plant code for the sending facility non-SAP',
    SOURCE_VALUE_STREAM_CODE COMMENT 'Sending valuestream within the source facility',
    PO_NUMBER COMMENT 'Part Order Number',
    PO_SCHEDULE_DUE_DATE COMMENT 'Scheduled Due Date for the PO',
    SCHEDULED_QUANTITY COMMENT 'Scheduled Quantity of pieces',
    SHIP_QUANTITY COMMENT 'Quantity of pieces actually shipped',
    RECEIVING_FACILITY_CODE 'Receiving Facility Code',
    DATA_SRC COMMENT 'Data Source',
    REFRESHED_TS COMMENT 'Refreshed Date. Last time the data was refreshed'
)

COMMENT = 'Data related to future demand'

AS

-- KK LEGACY DEMAND DATA
WITH KK_LEGACY_DEMAND AS (

SELECT 
    LEGACY_DEMAND.IDENT AS MATERIAL_NUM,
    LEGACY_DEMAND.RSF_I AS RSF_INDICATOR,
    NULL AS SOURCE_PLANT_CODE,
    'CZ' AS SOURCE_FACILITY_CODE,
    LEGACY_DEMAND.SCTN AS SOURCE_VALUE_STREAM_CODE,
    LEGACY_DEMAND.PO_NBR AS PO_NUMBER,
    LEGACY_DEMAND.PO_SCHD_DUE_DT AS PO_SCHEDULE_DUE_DATE,
    LEGACY_DEMAND.CUR_SCHD_QTY AS SCHEDULED_QUANTITY,
    LEGACY_DEMAND.SHP_QTY AS SHIP_QUANTITY,
    LEGACY_DEMAND.RCVG_FAC AS RECEIVING_FACILITY_CODE,
    'TBUPRODA_ISS_DMD_SCHD_TBL' AS DATA_SRC,
    LEGACY_DEMAND.REFRESHED_TS AS REFRESHED_TS
FROM
    EFDL_DEV_DB.DB2.TBUPRODA_ISS_DMD_SCHD_TBL LEGACY_DEMAND
    --  EFDL_DROD_DB.DB2.TBUPRODA_ISS_DMD_SCHD_TBL LEGACY_DEMAND
WHERE 
    LEGACY_DEMAND.PO_SCHD_DUE_DT >= CURRENT_DATE()
    AND LEGACY_DEMAND.REL_IND IN ('1', '0')
)

-- KK Legacy MAMM Demand
SELECT  
    KKLD.MATERIAL_NUM AS MATERIAL_NUM,
    KKLD.RSF_INDICATOR AS RSF_INDICATOR,
    NULL AS SOURCE_PLANT_CODE,
    KKLD.SOURCE_FACILITY_CODE AS SOURCE_FACILITY_CODE,
    KKLD.SCTN AS SOURCE_VALUE_STREAM_CODE,
    KKLD.PO_NBR AS PO_NUMBER,
    KKLD.PO_SCHD_DUE_DT AS PO_SCHEDULE_DUE_DATE,
    KKLD.CUR_SCHD_QTY AS SCHEDULED_QUANTITY,
    KKLD.SHP_QTY AS SHIP_QUANTITY,
    KKLD.RCVG_FAC AS RECEIVING_FACILITY_CODE,
    'TBUPRODA_ISS_DMD_SCHD_TBL' AS DATA_SRC,
    KKLD.REFRESHED_TS AS REFRESHED_TS
FROM KK_LEGACY_DEMAND KKLD
;
```

This is my error

Error occurred during SQL query execution

Reason:
SQL Error [1003] [42000]: SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 2 at position 1 unexpected 'MATERIAL_NUM'.

Answer (score 2):

Okay - so I have identified it with the help of a coworker. A few things went wrong here. First I forgot "COMMENT" on the create or replace view after RECEIVING_FACILITY_CODE

Should have been

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW SUPPLYCHAIN_LOGISTICS.DEMAND (   
    MATERIAL_NUM COMMENT 'Material or Part Number',
    RSF_INDICATOR COMMENT 'Rough(R), Semi-Finished(S), or Finished(F) Indicator',
    SOURCE_PLANT_CODE COMMENT 'Plant code for the sending facility related to SAP',
    SOURCE_FACILITY_CODE COMMENT 'Plant code for the sending facility non-SAP',
    SOURCE_VALUE_STREAM_CODE COMMENT 'Sending valuestream within the source facility',
    PO_NUMBER COMMENT 'Part Order Number',
    PO_SCHEDULE_DUE_DATE COMMENT 'Scheduled Due Date for the PO',
    SCHEDULED_QUANTITY COMMENT 'Scheduled Quantity of pieces',
    SHIP_QUANTITY COMMENT 'Quantity of pieces actually shipped',
    **RECEIVING_FACILITY_CODE COMMENT 'Receiving Facility Code',**
    DATA_SRC COMMENT 'Data Source',
    REFRESHED_TS COMMENT 'Refreshed Date. Last time the data was refreshed'
)
COMMENT = 'Data related to future demand'
```

However, at the end, near my select statement, it would have given an error as well. Because I did

```
KKLD.SCTN
```

Not

```
KKLD.SOURCE_VALUE_STREAM_CODE
```

Because I created a new table from another table

```
With KK_LEGACY_DEMAND AS 
( -- This is where I am creating the new table
    SELECT
        LEGACY_DEMAND.IDENT AS MATERIAL_NUM,
        LEGACY_DEMAND.RSF_I AS RSF_INDICATOR,
        NULL AS SOURCE_PLANT_CODE,
        'CZ' AS SOURCE_FACILITY_CODE,
        LEGACY_DEMAND.SCTN AS SOURCE_VALUE_STREAM_CODE,
        ....,
)
```

Now that I have that table called "KK_LEGACY_DEMAND" I need to select the columns I made on that table

Original Table = SCTN column

New Table I just made in the above lines = SOURCE_VALUE_STREAM_CODE column